# Bad idea: Responsive menu with resize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

Is it a bad idea to use jquery's `resize()` event to toggle an responsive menu?

Okay it's actually not an menu but the idea is almost the same:
I have an sidebar with 4 *boxes* with different informations. Below a specific `device-width` I *move* the sidebar to another place. Now each box is hidden and a `<selection>` shows up. When the selection changes it'll show the selected box.

```
$("#my_selection").change(function () {
    $.each(all, function () {                   // "all" are just my boxes
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var val = "#my_box_" + $(this).val();
    $(val).show();
});
```

---

I hope the concept is clear so far.
So but what happens when the user resizes the window? (aka changing orientation on mobile devices) Right:

Reducing width: Hide boxes
Increasing width again: Boxes are still missing

So.. that sucks. That's my solution:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    currentDisplay = $('#my_selection').css('display');

    if (currentDisplay == lastDisplay)
        return;

    lastDisplay = currentDisplay;

    if (currentDisplay == "none") {
        $.each(all, function () {
            $(this).show();
        })
    } else {
        $.each(all, function () {
            $(this).hide();
        })
    }
});
```

But I kinda have the feeling that this is a bit hacky, no? So - are there better solutions for this problem?

Here a simple sketch showing the design I've tried to explain.

[image: foo]

Comment: Generally I'd say there is nothing wrong with making things responsive through jQuery. Wouldn't it be easier to use a CSS media query though? And the `each()` loop doesn't really seem to be needed - you can give your boxes a class of `.boxes` and simply do `$('.boxes').hide()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I use media queries for everything. But when I hide them with javascript the media query won't work anymore when changing window size

Comment: Okay, I guess there's this value operation happening that's not easiliy mimicked with CSS. Just to throw some things out there that may come in handy - `.is(':visible')` and `toggle()`...